# How to send a newsletter from Magento?

Tags: magento, send, newsletter

I have a start-up and I want to send a newsletter to all my subscribers and customers, but I don't know how. I select the template and choose "Queue Newsletter" and set the date/time but it never sends. Have I done something wrong ? Does anyone know how to fix this ? Thanks

Comment: it's good form to "accept" an answer if it solved your problem. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Agree to Dick Laurent. You need to configure cron job. 
Tuned cron not only send newsletter, also it optimize DB (clear not used data).

Also if your don't have permission to cron configuration your can manual run newsletter send by open url:
http://yourstorename.com/index.php/admin/newsletter_queue/sending

Important your need to have disabled option "add secret key to url" to perform direct access to this action.